# I have a Expr value that have two child Expr in Scala, how can I execute this in tail position?

Tags: scala, recursion, tail-recursion

I have a bunch of Expr class defined like this:

```
sealed trait BoolExpr
sealed trait Value[T] {
  def get: T
}

final case class AndExpr(left: Expr, right: Expr) extends BoolExpr
final case class EqualsExpr[T](value: Value[T], expectedValue: T) extends BoolExpr
```

And after I constructed the whole BoolExpr value, I will execute it by using a function like this one:

```
def exec(expr: BoolExpr) = {
  expr match {
    case EqualsExpr(value, expectedValue) => value.get == expectedValue
    case AndExpr(left: Expr, right: Expr) => exec(left) && exec(right)
  }
}
```

This is not good enough because it is a normal recursive.

I'm planning to refactor the `exec` function by using trampoline.

Using trampoline requires that every time this function call something else, the call should in tail position in order to warp in the trampoline.

But I cannot find a way to rewrite the `exec(left) && exec(right)` part into a tail call style.

Is there a way I can do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on the right path here with a trampoline. Take a look at either [Cats](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/master/free/src/main/scala/cats/free/Trampoline.scala) or Scalaz's Trampoline implementation (which are based on the [Free Monad](http://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/freemonad.html).) Or you can use vanilla Scala in the [scala.util.control.TailCalls](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/control/TailCalls$.html) package. Since all of these are Monads by design, you can do the following:

```
import util.control.TailCalls._

def exec(expr: BoolExpr) = expr match{
  case EqalsExpr(value, expectedValue) => done(value.get == expectedValue)
  case AndExpr(left, right) => exec(left).flatMap{
    l => exec(right).map(l && _)
  }
}
```

Note here that the calls to `map` and `flatMap` preserve the properties of a Trampoline and will not ever cause the stack to explode.